# Using the WSL terminal with Neovim

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, shell, wsl, execute

I have Neovim installed on Windows. I use WSL for running Python and C code. So I'd like to map a key to get Neovim to run a shell command in WSL directly from the Neovim editor. But I seem to be running into an issue I haven't been able to fix on my own. When I run `:!python3 %`, this is the output I get:

[image]

I did try to solve this by myself, here's more information.

I added the following two lines to my init.lua.

```
vim.opt.shell='wsl.exe'
vim.cmd('set shellcmdflag="-c"')
```

If I input the `:term` command, a new WSL instance opens in the editor, in the same directory - just as expected. I know that the shebang is okay because from this newly opened terminal window both `python3 code.py` and `./code.py` execute just as expected. The problem seems to be exclusively with the exclamation mark command.

Could I have some help with this? The end goal is a way to link Neovim key mappings to terminal commands, if there is some other (better?) way to do it.

Comment: It seems that bash is try to execute the program named `python3 code.py`, which means the arguments it got from `:!` weren’t handled right somewhere. Can you share the values of the various shell and redirect options?

Comment: I haven't added any shell and redirect options besides the ones I've mentioned. Are you looking for anything specific? If these are env variables, what commands can I run to show you what you need to see?

Another anomaly I noticed - with the exclamation mark method, it seems like `/bin/bash` is being used. But with the `:term` method (which has no issues at all), running `which bash` tells me that `/usr/bin/bash` is being used. Is this a red herring or might it be related to the issue?

Comment: I also fail to start commands with arguments on Neovim with WSL as a shell.

Comment: I found a workaround. I have updated the solution accordingly ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gVim I would do:

```
set shell=wsl.exe
set shellcmdflag=
set shellquote=
set shellxquote=
```

With Neovim I suspect there is a weakness in the way arguments are passed to the spawned process.

The workaround I have found is:

Create a `wsl.bat` file in your path:

```
wsl.exe %*
```

```
set shell=cmd\ /c\ wsl.bat
set shellcmdflag=
set shellquote=
set shellxquote=
```

Comment: You guys are absolute legends!! It worked. Quick question, could you break down the `set shell=` line? I gather the `cmd` bit at the beginning of the arguments tells Nvim to invoke cmd first, then call a bat file which inserts a `wsl.exe` before the commands, instructing cmd to invoke those commands with WSL...right? What does the `/c` do?

Comment: I didn't had the time to dig into the code of Neovim and I should take the time to fill a big report but it seems that Neovim pass all the arguments as one argument  a bit like if it was `'python3 yourscript.py'` instead of `python3 yourscript.py` and `wsl` get confused. Maybe your trick could work. Worth trying :-) The `/c` make the `cmd` standard shell execute the command and return.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)